# How to change default shopping list app with google home

Tags: google-home

With Alexa I can change default shopping list and todo app by settings.

I'm using `AnyList` with Alexa, so can I also use `AnyList` with Google home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnyList has been updated to work with Google Assistant now, I use it myself. You just need to go into the settings for Google Home and change the default list to AnyList.

https://help.anylist.com/articles/enable-google-assistant/

> Set a default list service
>
> Let your Google Assistant create and edit lists in a service, like Google Keep.
>
> On your Android phone or tablet, open the Google Assistant app Assistant (iOS)
>   At the top right, tap your profile image or initial and then Services and then Notes & Lists.
>   Tap a service to set it as your default.
>   To confirm, tap Continue.
>   Any new lists created with your Google Assistant will be visible on your default list service. Any lists you created with your Google Assistant before you set a default list service, won’t be available on that service.
>
> Important: If you choose a third-party provider app as your default, that provider’s app's privacy policy applies.

Answer (score 1):

You can't

Google used to support Google Keep for shopping lists, but they changed it to use Google Express.

Express is only available in the US (at time of writing) and you can only access a web app to see the list elsewhere. You can access this by asking the assistant on your phone to show the list or clicking on the link in the Services tab in the assistant settings.

Edit

Given it looks like Google are sitting down Express we can only hope we get Google Keep integration back or a choice.
 https://techcrunch.com/2019/09/11/google-express-to-close-in-a-few-weeks-will-become-part-of-google-shopping/